# Why is it okay to do this?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, asymptotics

I am studying asymptotic recurrences for algorithms, and the book says:

$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + \Theta (n)$$

is technically

$$T(n) = T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + \Theta (n)$$

for an algorithm (e.g. Mergesort). However apparently it's okay to analyze the running time using the first recurrence. Why is it okay to approximate the second recurrence with the first one?

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in the asymptotic behaviour; you can show that any $T$ satisfying the second relation is monotone (increasing), and then you can use the "sandwiching" theorem to relate solutions to the second to solutions to the first —up to some term which will, in hindsight (once you have the solution to the first relation) prove to be negligible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lost. An example might help - could you maybe use the sandwiching theorem to relate the recurrences in my question?

Comment: In your specific example (I didn't go through the whole derivation, so it's more the general sketch), I reckon one could for instance solve
$$
T^+(n)=2T^+(n/2+1)+\Theta(n)\\
T^-(n)=2T^-(n/2-1)+\Theta(n)
$$
and show they give the same asymptotic behavior $f(n)$. Then, if $T$ is defined as the "correct" one (satisfying your second recurrence relation), one has $T^-(n)\leq T(n)\leq T^+(n)$, so $T(n)$ has also asymptotic behavior $f(n)$.